# 5.61b University physics with modern physics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram, statics

[image: 5.61]

$$
\sum F_{y} = 0
$$
$$
\sum F_{y} = T_{1y} + T_{2y} - mg
$$
$$
mg = (4400N)\sin{60} + (4400N)\sin{40}
$$
$$
mg = 6640N
$$
Why is this wrong?

**solution**

$T_{1x}$ has to be equal to $T_{2x}$ 
$$T_{1x} = 4400N cos(60)$$
$$T_{2x} = a cos(40)$$
$$4400N cos(60) = a cos(40)$$
$$a = \frac{4400N cos(60)}{cos(40)}$$
$$mg = 4400N sin(60) + a cos(40)$$

Comment: Please note that homework and exercise questions should focus on a conceptual question, and show some effort.  See the meta discussion [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).  What factors have you thought about when determining if it's right or wrong?  Have you tried to check these values in a different context to make sure they make sense?

Comment: @JMac is there anywhere I can ask questions like this? With book name and question number

Comment: If you have access to the stack exchange chat (I'm not sure if you do or not yet), I can give you some advice in the [problem solving strategies](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54160/problem-solving-strategies) chat.

Comment: @JMac [Talk in chat requires 20 rep](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat), though you might be able to invite OP into a chat room, which I believe gives them write access to that room.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Because the force on each wire isn't the same. You can't just plug in $4400N$ as the force on each. Try balancing the vertical and horizontal components separately.